# How to insert product in shopping cart in a new row if exists but the color and size is different in Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, sql, stored-procedures

I have the stored procedure that adds a product to shopping cart. But If a product exists ina shopping cart, and i choose the same product but this time i also choose a different size or color, i want to add a new row in the shopping cart and not to update the existing row with the cart id.
Here is the SP:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ShoppingCartAddItem]
(@CartId char(36),
 @ProductId int,
 @Attributes nvarchar(1000))
AS
If Exists(Select CartId From ShoppingCart
Where ProductId = @ProductId and CartId = @CartId AND Attributes = @Attributes)
Insert Into ShoppingCart (CartId, ProductId, Attributes, Quantity, DateAdded)
Values (@CartId, @ProductId, @Attributes, 1, GETDATE())
Else
If Exists(Select CartId from ShoppingCart Where ProductId = @ProductId And CartId = @CartId)
UPDATE ShoppingCart
Set Quantity = Quantity + 1
WHere ProductId = @ProductId And CartId = @CartId
Else
If Exists(Select ProductName From Products Where ProductId = @ProductId)
Insert Into ShoppingCart (CartId, ProductId, Attributes, Quantity, DateAdded)
Values (@CartId, @ProductId, @Attributes, 1, GETDATE())
```

Does Someone has any idea on how to fix this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saying that one cart can only have one instance of a given item.
You would need to add a check for the attributes as well.  If the attributes are update quantity otherwise insert a new record.

```
If Exists(Select CartId From ShoppingCart Where ProductId = @ProductId and CartId = @CartId AND Attributes = @Attributes)
  BEGIN
     UPDATE ShoppingCart Set Quantity = Quantity + 1 
       WHere ProductId = @ProductId And CartId = @CartId  AND Attributes = @Attributes
  END
Else   
  BEGIN  
      Insert Into ShoppingCart (CartId, ProductId, Attributes, Quantity, DateAdded) Values (@CartId, @ProductId, @Attributes, 1, GETDATE()) 
  END
```

Comment: Thanks Chad, I am not saying that the cart should have one instance of the given item. For example if a product (e.g shirt, color:blue, size: L) is in the cart and then i choose the same product but with different size and color, this time i want to add a new instance in the cart of the same product. But if the product has the same attributes i want to update the quantity only.

Comment: Which is what i believe the code above does.  I meant with your code you were saying that... sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Unfortunately the code does not works as said, it does not add the product to the cart even it does not update the current product quantity if the product is in the cart.

Comment: Actually it updates the current product quantity but does not add a new instance if the product has different attributes. Sorry for the above statement.

Comment: Added some begin and ends that may have confused the issue

Comment: I just altered my SP, with the updated code that you provided but still the same. I dont know where is the problem.

Comment: Have you tried running the script in sql management studio to try and do an insert to see if that will work?

Comment: I just tried in Sql Management Studio and it works, i think i have to check the insert code. But the SP works.

Comment: @Chad, Could you be able to check if I upload a code if it correct related to SP above?

Comment: I can try if you still need help.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ShoppingCartAddItem]
(@CartId char(36),
 @ProductId int,
 @Attributes nvarchar(1000))
AS
If Exists(Select CartId from ShoppingCart Where ProductId = @ProductId And CartId = @CartId AND Attributes = @Attributes)
    UPDATE ShoppingCart
    Set Quantity = Quantity + 1
    Where ProductId = @ProductId And CartId = @CartId AND Attributes = @Attributes
Else
    Insert Into ShoppingCart (CartId, ProductId, Attributes, Quantity, DateAdded)
    Values (@CartId, @ProductId, @Attributes, 1, GETDATE())
```

Comment: If the product is in the cart and i choose the same product with the same attributes it works and updates the quantity, but when i choose different attributes for the same product it does not add the item to the cart (as a new instance).

Comment: Thanks for the information the SP above was completely right but it seemed i have some code bugs while inserting, because i tried from Sql Management Studio and it worked. Thanks again